# AppEngine: Out of Blobstore and into S3?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, amazon-s3, blobstore

I'm uploading data to the blobstore. There should it stay only temporary and be uploaded from within my AppEngine app to Amazon S3.

As it seems I can only get the data through a BlobDonwloadHandler as described at the Blobstore API: http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html#Serving_a_Blob

So I tried to fetch that blob specific download URL from within my application (remember my question yesterday). Fetching internal URLs from within the AppEngine (not the development server) is working, even it´s bad style - I know.

But getting the blob is not working. My code looks like:

```
result = urllib2.urlopen('http://my-app-url.appspot.com/get_blob/'+str(qr.blob_key))
```

And I'm getting

> DownloadError: ApplicationError: 2
>
> Raised by:
>
> File
>   "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/urlfetch.py",
>   line 332, in _get_fetch_result
>       raise DownloadError(str(err))

Even after searching I really don't know what to do.

All tutorials I've seen are focusing only on serving through a URL back to the user. But I want to retrieve the blob from the Blobstore and send it to a S3 bucket. Anyone any idea how I could realize that or is that even not possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why not upload the file directly to S3?

Comment: @Nick: one reason to do this is to have GAE resize the photo.

Comment: @Nick: I´m using S3 and GoogleStorage for permanent storage, the users are uploading to the blobstore first and deciding later where there data has to be saved.

Comment: @Michael This seems unnecessarily kludgy - and it'll also limit you to 1MB, since that's all you can send with URLFetch. It's possible to do form-based uploads to S3; this would be a far neater approach.

Comment: @Nick: This App should be a kind of storage management solution for different private and public cloud services (Amazon S3, Google Storage, Walrus from Eucalyptus, etc.) The allocation to different services should be done by the AppEngine to save users time and bandwith. Using form-based uploads will triple users bandwith needs. I will try Calvins approach using the BlobReader class, perhaps I can realize some "dirty" workaraound.

Comment: @Michael App Engine is a poor choice, then, since it can't handle arbitrary size payloads directly (only via blobstore).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a BlobReader to access that Blob and send that to S3.

http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobreaderclass.html

Comment: Be careful not to timeout uploading really large files from GAE to S3.

Comment: @Amir: How this should work? Calling blob_reader = blobstore.BlobReader(blob_key, buffer_size=1048576) in a loop and appending to a S3 upload stream? Boto doesn´t support that, if you take a look at botos upload methods like the set_contents_from_string method - there is no possibility to send small chunks (like 1MB) one after another. So the BlobReader class will not help in that case, or did I overlook something?

Comment: I've never used boto, but you should be able to read the entire blob into a buffer object and encode and send that (perhaps using set_contents_from_file?).  You can pretend a buffer is a file using StringIO.